# Zend Framework: How to write a correct model that use another table?

Tags: zend-framework, model, zend-framework-mvc

I have models in project that use more than one table to select.

How can I write code like this more correct?

> public function __construct()
>      {
>
> ```
>    $this->_name = DB_PREFIX . 'teachers';
>    parent::__construct();
> ```
>
> }
>
> public function init()
>     {
>
> ```
>   $this->db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
> ```
>
> }
>
> public function getTeachers($course_id)
>     {
>
> ```
>   $students_query = $this ->db->select()
>                           ->from($this->_name, '')
>                           ->from(<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>, array('uid', 'ulogin'))
>                           ->where("<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>.uid = {$this->_name}.teacher_id")
>                           ->where("{$this->_name}.course_id = ?", $course_id)
>                            ->order("<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>.ulogin");
>
>   $result = $this->db->fetchAll($students_query) ? $this->db->fetchAll($students_query) : NULL;
>
>   return $result;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Just so you know 

`$result = $this->db->fetchAll($students_query) ? $this->db->fetchAll($students_query) : NULL;`

Can be written as

`return $this->db->fetchAll($students_query);`

Without executing your query twice. If no records are returned, fetchAll() will return null already.

Comment: thank you, your advise made it more perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$students_query =  $this->db->select()
                          ->from($this->_name, '')
                          ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                          ->join('<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>', "<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>.uid = {$this->_name}.teacher_id", array('uid', 'ulogin'))
                          ->where("{$this->_name}.course_id = ?", $course_id)
                          ->order("<ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>.ulogin");
```

Comment: ok, but how to get this <ANOTHER_TABLE_NAME>? I think it's not very good to write it as string. And when I try to get it from model it fails.

Comment: Set a class property? `private $secondTable = "foo";`